# Convert vimeo link into an embed link in python

Tags: python, django, regex

I am using Python and django, and I have some vimeo URLs I need to convert to their embed versions. For example, this:
https://vimeo.com/76979871
has to be converted into this:
https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871
but Not converted

My code is below:

```
_vm =  re.compile(
    r'/(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/|groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(\d+)\/video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)/', re.I)
_vm_format = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/{0}'
def replace(match):
    groups = match.groups()
    print(_vm_format)
    return _vm_format.format(groups[5])
return _vm.sub(replace, text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The given regular expression fits several variants of Vimeo URL:

```
https://vimeo.com/76979871
https://vimeo.com/channels/76979871
https://vimeo.com/groups/sdf/videos/76979871
https://vimeo.com/album/12321/video/76979871
```

The video number, provided it is really the only thing that you need for your player, will be in capture group 1 (`groups[1]`) after you slightly correct the regular expression: `r'(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/|groups\/(?:[^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(?:\d+)\/video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)'`. All other parentheses are non-capturing groups.

If, however, the player code is different for different URL types, then you better split your regular expression in four; and there will be different replacements for each.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `\` from both the end and use capture group 3 to get video id

```regex
(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/|groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(\d+)\/video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)
```

**Example**

```py
import re

_vm =  re.compile(
    r'(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/|groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(\d+)\/video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)', re.I)
_vm_format = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/{0}'

def replace(match):
    groups = match.groups()
    return _vm_format.format(groups[2])

urls=["https://vimeo.com/76979871",
    "https://vimeo.com/channels/76979871",
    "https://vimeo.com/groups/sdf/videos/76979871",
    "https://vimeo.com/album/12321/video/76979871"]
for u in urls:
    print(_vm.sub(replace, u))
```

**Output**

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871
https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871
https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871
https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871
```